# Webpack and Node server cross browser request

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, fetch

I am new to react and using the create-react-app as a starting point.  I have an api that returns json data.  I run my api using a node server on port 3000.

I also have the default create-react-app setup that kicks off the app using port 3000.  I want to fetch data from my api and render it play with it in my react app.  I get the error that the data cannot be retrieved because of cross origin requests.  How does this typically get handled in webpack?

Below is my code, but I would essentially want to make a call like: `NodeFetch('/api/jobs')` to access the returned data from my api running on port 3001.

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import NodeFetch from 'node-fetch' 

class NodeFetchData extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      jobs: []
    };
  }


  componentDidMount() {

    NodeFetch('http://codepen.io/jobs.json')
    .then(res => {
      this.setState({ jobs:res.data.jobs });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {this.state.jobs.map(job =>
            <li key={job.hashid}>{job.company_name}</li>
          )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default NodeFetchData;
```

Comment: Show some code to suggest something

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, when using Webpack you need to keep in mind the difference between testing your development code locally and deploying your application to a production environment.

The above because, when in "development" mode, Webpack takes care of serving you app locally, but when it comes to your production environment, all Webpack should do is to pack your React.js app in a bundle which would in turn be served by an actual HTTP server.

With the previous in mind, in your specific case you're having issues testing your development code locally, this because of the port difference between the server and the API (3000/3001).

You'll want to make sure you use relative routes when fetching so that:

`NodeFetch('http://localhost:3001/api/jobs.json')`

becomes:

`NodeFetch('/api/jobs.json')`

And in your Webpack config you'll want to use a `proxy` line like the following:

```
  proxy: {
    '/api': {
      target: 'http://localhost:3001',
      secure: false
    }
  }
```

For further reading on the subject you can take a look the following article which I wrote covering the issue detailed here as well as another way CORS can be managed:

[Webpack and CORS - Demystifying Cross-server Communications in React.js](https://jean.ml/437U6E)

It includes a version controlled `Hello World` sample with solutions to CORS errors in development environments and an opinionated Webpack configuration which adheres to common production-ready React.js app standards.

Comment: awesome! thank you so much. I will look into it when I get a chance and see if I can get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by simply adding a proxy line in my package.json.  I then kicked off by server in a separate terminal.  I'm now trying to figure out how to kick off both the api server and the react client app.

```
{
  "name": "scrap",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001/",
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "0.7.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "foreman": "^2.0.0",
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Comment: As an FYI, the sample within the article I mentioned in my answer includes a way of configuring your app so that you run your server and API from a single command, both for development and production environments.